# how to create a post having a custom field meta value via the WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, custom-fields

I have registered a post type and can create new posts of that type via the rest api.
however, i cannot seem to add any post meta i.e. custom fields.

here is the data i send:

```
$data = array(
    
"title" => $post->name,
"content" => $record->content,
"status" => "draft",
"author" => "1",
"meta" => array( "test" => "test" )
```

);

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USER:PASSWORD");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec( $ch );

curl_close( $ch );
```

to be sure, i have also created a specific meta, although i don't know if this even works or does anything.

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_meta_function' );
function register_meta_function() {
    
    $meta_args = array(
        'type'         => 'string',
        'description'  => 'test',
        'single'       => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    );
    register_meta( 'POST_TYPE', 'test', $meta_args );
    
}
```

with a post type, i can at least see in the menu, that it has been created, but i cannot see that meta field anywhere.

does anyone have experience with the wordpress rest api and knows where the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing:

`add_action( 'init', 'register_meta_function' );`

with

`add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_meta_function' );`

Then test your update via the REST API to see if the meta field value appears on the edit page for the post.

Your options for displaying the meta field value when viewing the post (on the front-end) depend on whether you are using a client-side solution (e.g. [enqueued scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), the [data module](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/)) or a server-side solution (e.g. [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter hook).

### UPDATE

Updating meta values for custom post types has to be handled differently compared to the WordPress core post type. The solution to the problem could be in this Stack Exchange question: [Add post meta fields, when creating a post using WordPress' REST API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/380513), which was borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384841). The solution is outlined below. In the function below, replace the text CUSTOM_POST_TYPE with the name of your custom post type.

```
/**
 * Update post meta for CUSTOM_POST_TYPE.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_insert_this-post_type/
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/
 */
function post_meta_update( \WP_Post $post, \WP_REST_Request $request, bool $creating ): void {
    $metas = $request->get_param( 'meta' );
    if ( is_array( $metas ) ) {
        foreach ( $metas as $meta_name => $meta_value ) {
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_name, $meta_value );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'rest_insert_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE', 'post_meta_update', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: thank you for the info. sadly the meta value does not appear. also, there doesn't seem to be an error happening because the post is created.

Comment: @composersucks It's possible your meta fields are currently hidden. With the latest versions of WordPress (e.g. version 6), you can display or hide meta fields on the Edit Page by using the Options menu. To display these fields enable the Custom fields option. You will find it from the Edit Page here: Options (3 dots at top-right) > Preferences > Panels (left menu) > Custom fields (under Additional).

Comment: thanks, but they are not hidden. could there be something wrong with the data of the request?

Comment: @composersucks I ran a test with your data using [apiFetch](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-api-fetch/) and it worked. I saw the meta data value appear on the Edit Page. Assuming you are not using a custom post type, I used `register_meta('post', 'test', $meta_args);`. Could you please explain how you are sending the POST to the REST API? For example, are you using wp_remote_post, cURL, or something else? It could be helpful to see that code. Perhaps the value for the "meta" key needs to be a string (e.g. using json_encode) rather than an array.

Comment: thank you very for the patience! i use a custom post type. i use curl and have added that code to my initial post.

Comment: it worked! thank you very much! i did see that snippet before, but it looked so strange, that i assumed it was for something more complicated.