# Wordpress Rest API Meta description

Tags: wordpress, rest

I am sending posts with WordPress rest API, but I can't send meta description. Where did I go wrong?

```
wp_api_url = "https://xxxxx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
wp_auth_token = "xxxxxxx"

import requests
meta = {
    "description": "test description",
    "keywords": "test keywords",
    "tags": "test Tag"
}

data = {
    "title": conttitle,
    "content": contcontent,
    "status": "publish",
    "data": {"filter": "raw", "meta": meta}

        }

# Set headers for WordPress REST API request
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {wp_auth_token}",
}
response = requests.post(wp_api_url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The arguments available to create a core WordPress Post are listed [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments-2). The argument `data` is not listed there (and may not be valid). `meta` and `tags` are top level arguments. `meta` is not a property of `data`. `tags` ([Post tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/)) is not a property of `meta`.

Try rearranging the json payload as follows:

### json payload

```
meta = {
    "description": "test description",
    "keywords": "test keywords",
    "filter": "raw" // This might not apply. See note under 'filter' below.***
}

data = {
    "title": conttitle,
    "content": contcontent,
    "status": "publish",
    "tags": "test Tag",
    "meta": meta
}
```

### filter

***The filter value might not apply to your case. You could be thinking of the 'context' argument used when [sanitizing Posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_post/#parameters).

### custom post type

If trying to save meta data for a custom post type, please see the answer to this question: [how to create a post having a custom field meta value via the WP REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75668223).

## UPDATE

To avoid [extending the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/), you could try using the [rest_insert_{$this->post_type}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_insert_this-post_type/) action hook with the standard [wp-json/wp/v2/posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) REST API Base Route to create posts and [RankMath's hooks](https://rankmath.com/kb/filters-hooks-api-developer/#unlimited-keywords) to update RankMath properties. See example below.

### Untested code

```
/**
 * RankMath SEO's filter hook callback.
 * Allow changing the meta keywords from the default Focus Keywords.
 * @see https://rankmath.com/kb/filters-hooks-api-developer/#unlimited-keywords
 *
 * @param string $keywords Keywords.
 */
function rank_math_focus_keyword_hook_callback( string $keywords ) {
    return $keywords;
}
add_filter( 'rank_math/frontend/keywords', 'rank_math_focus_keyword_hook_callback', 10, 1 );


/**
 * Called when post is created or updated via WP REST API.
 * POST_TYPE can be core WordPress 'post', or a custom post type.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_insert_this-post_type/
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/
 */
function post_updates_for_rankmath( \WP_Post $post, \WP_REST_Request $request, bool $creating ): void {
    // If post is updated and not created, exit the function.
    if ( ! $creating ) {
        return;
    }

    $desired_meta_keys = array( 'filter', 'whatever', 'etc' );
    $keyword_meta_key = 'keywords';

    // Example of updating meta data for recently created post.
    $metas = $request->get_param( 'meta' );
    if ( is_array( $metas ) ) {
        foreach ( $metas as $meta_name => $meta_value ) {
            if ( in_array( $meta_name, $desired_meta_keys ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_name, $meta_value );
            } elseif ( $meta_name == $keyword_meta_key ) {

                // Example of updating RankMath focus keywords.
                apply_filters( 'rank_math/frontend/keywords', $meta_value );
            }
        }
    }

}

// Below, replace POST_TYPE with the name of the post type.
add_action( 'rest_insert_POST_TYPE', 'post_updates_for_rankmath', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I am using RankMath SEO. How can I update "focus keyword" and "Description" with api. I couldn't find any documentation or example about it.

Comment: Hi @Berk. RankMath SEO website has examples using filters that they provide. See [Filter to change the Focus Keyword Limit](https://rankmath.com/kb/filters-hooks-api-developer/#unlimited-keywords), and for the **Description** see [Filter to add custom variable replacements](https://rankmath.com/kb/filters-hooks-api-developer/#add-custom-variable). Their [Rank Math SEO Filters and Hooks for Developers](https://rankmath.com/kb/filters-hooks-api-developer/) page probably has everything you need. Better support [might be here](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/seo-by-rank-math/).

Comment: @Berk If you must use REST API you should extend it and use RankMath's server-side filters and hooks. You will need these WP functions: [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), [add_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/), [wp_set_object_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/), [register_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/), [register_rest_route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) and others.

Comment: code works, but only if you fix the typo:
( $meta_name == $keyword_meta_key ) )
to this: 
( $meta_name == $keyword_meta_key ) and of course do not forget to change the 'rest_insert_POST_TYPE' to the 'rest_insert_post' or other...

Comment: @KamilB. Thanks. Typo is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rest API wp/v2/posts/{id} endpoint with the below data:

```
data =  {
  "title": conttitle,
  "content": contcontent,
  "status": "publish",
  "meta": {
    "description": "This is the meta description of the post."
  }
}
```

This will update the post meta description. also check https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post

Comment: I am using RankMath SEO. How can I update "focus keyword" and "Description" with api. I couldn't find any documentation or example about it.